# Angularfire2 - how to Reverse the observable list

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, real-time, angularfire2

I'm using this code to reverse the list:

`this.items = this.db.list('/privacy').map( (array) => {return array.reverse()} ) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;`

and l called the list in this way:

`<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
{{item.order}}</ion-item>`

and this work for me (the array was reversed).
but my problem not here, my problem is when a new data pushed to the list
the order of the list messed up!. After refreshing the page the order reverse again.

> this is a chat application not professional way to reload the page or restart the app.

Comment: Did you try using the `subscribe` mechanism instead of the async pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.db.list('/privacy',{
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'createDate' //replace with the field you want to order by
  }
  })
  .subscribe((items: any[]) =>{
    return items.reverse();
  })
```

Comment: That's ugly. Also there is noting wrong with the pipe.

Comment: Use of pipe is subjective. I did not say anything wrong with the use of pipe

Comment: @alltej  sorry doesnt work, but i dont use the query! because just i nedd to reverse it

Comment: @RamadanKhaled Did you try using the query? I think you have to supply this because it needs to know what order it needs to be returned and you have the option to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

This works when working with an observable array

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (items | async).?reverse()">
```

Not sure if this applies to AngularFireLists